# Who was the first programmer?

Tags: history

Is there some consensus among historians on who was the first programmer ever? If so, who was it and what were they programming on?

I find it more interesting to know more about the pioneers of programming, regardless if they programmed on a programmable machine or if they've designed the machine themselves to do some computing task.

Comment: Define programming precisely enough so that we know if we have to consider things like preparing tapes for Jacquard's loom or not.

Comment: The first one ever to write code :)))

Comment: I vote for counting Jacquard.

Comment: Related question: [Who was the first software engineer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/149880/1683)

Comment: Those who calculated eclipses in the Mayan calendar, might very well have been the first programmers.  You need to design an algorithm ("are we close enough?") and execute it.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

[Augusta Ada King](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ada_Lovelace), Countess of Lovelace (1815 - 1852) is credited by most as the first programmer.

The first program was an algorithm to calculate [Bernoulli numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number) for Charles Babbage's [Analytical Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytical_engine), and it appeared in her translation notes of [Luigi Menabrea's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luigi_Menabrea) memoir ["Sketch of the Analytical Engine Invented by Charles Babbage"](http://www.fourmilab.ch/babbage/sketch.html), more specifically [Note G](http://www.fourmilab.ch/babbage/sketch.html#NoteG). That said, the math necessary for calculating Bernoulli numbers were known long before Ada's time, however Ada's algorithm is the first instance of a calculating algorithm designed to be executed by a (at the time still hypothetical) machine.

[Konrad Zuse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konrad_Zuse) (1910 – 1995) is also a solid candidate for the "first programmer" moniker, having invented a floating point binary mechanical calculator with limited programmability, the [Z1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z1_%28computer%29) (1936) but more importantly the [Z3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z3_%28computer%29) (1941), a [Turing complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness) [electro-mechanical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromechanical) computer.

When it comes to electronic computers, the [Atanasoff–Berry Computer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atanasoff%E2%80%93Berry_Computer) (conceived in 1937, operational by 1942) is credited as the first electronic digital computing device, so it's reasonable to think of its designers, [John Vincent Atanasoff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Vincent_Atanasoff) and [Clifford Berry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_Berry) as programming pioneers. The Atanasoff–Berry Computer wasn't programmable though, the first programmable electronic computer was [ENIAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ENIAC) (1946).

Although ENIAC's designers [John Mauchly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Mauchly) and [J. Presper Eckert](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._Presper_Eckert) probably did a fair share of programming, most of ENIAC's programming were done by these [lovely ladies](http://www.eniacprogrammers.org/index.shtml):

> [image: ENIAC programmers, courtesy of the ENIAC Programmers Project]

Their names from left to right are Kathy Kleiman<sup>1</sup>, [Jean Bartik](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Bartik), [Marlyn Meltzer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marlyn_Meltzer), [Kay Mauchly Antonelli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kathleen_Antonelli) and [Betty Holberton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betty_Holberton) at the front. Two of the ENIAC's female programmers, [Fran Bilas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frances_Spence) and [Ruth Lichterman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruth_Teitelbaum), are missing from the photo.

When it comes to digital computers, the first one was [Colossus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colossus_computer) (operational by December 1943), and the project's lead [Tommy Flowers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tommy_Flowers) (1905 – 1998) should also be considered a programming pioneer, along with [Max Newman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_Newman) (1897 – 1984) who was responsible for formulating the requirements for the machine and of course [Alan Turing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Turing) (1912 – 1954), who had designed Bletchley Park's earlier electromechanical cryptanalytical machine, the [Bombe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombe) (1939), and was influential in Colossus design<sup>2</sup>.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Kathy Kleiman is the founder of the [ENIAC Programmers Project](http://www.eniacprogrammers.org/index.shtml) and obviously not an ENIAC programmer (too young :)</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> [A History of Computing in the Twentieth Century: The Colossus](http://www.cs.ncl.ac.uk/research/pubs/books/papers/133.pdf) - B. Randell, Newcastle University (PDF)</sub>

Comment: Since the Analytical Engine never was built (Babbage only built a small model) it would be interesting to know who first programmed on a computer that was built.

Comment: @Spoike: That would have to be the machine built to crack the Enigma at Bletchley Park in 194..something.

Comment: 'Brogrammers' is a load of crap dreamed up by bloggers.

Comment: @DeadMG, Zuse Z1 dates from late 30's and thus is earlier.  There is also probably a need to define programmable computer before because early machines lacked often characteristic we take for granted.

Comment: @DeadMG Enigma was first broken in 1932 by the [Biuro Szyfrów](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_Cipher_Bureau), but their techniques have little to do with programming (they build one for themselves and cracked it). As for Bletchley, the [Bombe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombe) was electromechanical and was build in 1939 so it loses to Zuse's Z1 and the [Colossus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colossus_computer) was operational in 1944, so it loses to ABC but not to ENIAC (will update the answer).

Comment: It always seemed a little strange to me that Babbage himself is not considered the first programmer. How can you design a machine and not make some algorithms for it in the process? Of course, this is a beautiful legend, and I'm kind of trying to make things more prosaic, so I'm sorry about that.

Comment: @Malcolm That's a very good question. What you need to remember is that the Analytical Engine wasn't build during Babbage's lifetime and that Ada didn't discover the math for her algorithm, but translated the math to a form that would have worked for the Analytical Engine (which is what qualifies her algorithm as software and not math). It's not unthinkable that Babbage did come up with an earlier program, but never documented it. However he did document Ada's involvement, in p. 136 of _Passages from the life of a philosopher_:

Comment: (cont...) "I then suggested that she add some notes to Menabrea's memoir, an idea which was immediately adopted. We discussed together the various illustrations that might be introduced: I suggested several but the selection was entirely her own. So also was the algebraic working out of the different problems, except, indeed, that relating to the numbers of Bernoulli, which I had offered to do to save Lady Lovelace the trouble. This she sent back to me for an amendment, having detected a grave mistake which I had made in the process."

Comment: (cont...) And although it might seem that Babbage is claiming at least some of the credit (which would be fair as the two worked together), he never contested Ada's notes on the memoir, that carried only her name.

Comment: In 1941 Zuse hired a blind mathematician named _Arnold Fast_ to program his computers. This guy was probably the world's first _professional_ programmer.

Comment: Someone finally debunked that Ada wrote the first program: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/32793/22870.

Answer (score 12):

**Archimedes could also qualify**

Since he is *tentatively* credited with the creation of the [Antikythera mechanism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antikythera_mechanism) (an example of an early [analog computer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_computer#Precursors)) some 2000 years ago, at some point he must have made the decision to calculate a particular event.

That act could be thought of as a program, thus he became a programmer.

Comment: The mechanism is not programmable.

Comment: No, but the starting points are and that constitutes a calculation which is essentially all a program is. Think of it as find_event(x) and Archimedes chose and entered x. He also, potentially, built the hardware to support the implementation of find_event(x).

Comment: My point is that a computational device does not a programmable computer make.

Comment: I disagree, I think that programming is "the process of designing, writing, testing, debugging, and maintaining the source code of computer programs". In this case the source code is the paper and blueprints to create and operate the device. Since he potentially created the device, he qualifies under that definition.

Comment: Although a connection to Archimedes is implied, the claim that he is "tentatively credited with the creation of the Antikythera mechanism" is quite a bold one (yes, I didn't miss tentatively).

Comment: @YannisRizos Yeah, I'm on very thin ice with this one. I'm sure the community overall will settle on Ada Lovelace as the clear winner, but I just wanted to present a case for alternative consideration.

Comment: @Gary: One important distinction for programmability, at least as it's understood today, is that the program exists independent of the hardware.  The Antikythera mechanism was "hard-coded" to calculate one thing, but there was no way to input other programs.

Comment: @Gary You may be on very thin ice, but I couldn't resist my Greek pride and upvoted your answer ;)

Comment: You made an interesting point, but I think this would only be valid (my humble opinion), if you declare the real world to be the ultimate Turing Machine (which then can be programmed by our activities). In this case nearly any toolmaking or processing would be "programming".

Comment: It looks like we're debating more on WHAT IS A PROGRAMMER. Someone who creates a mechanism embedding in it some logic isn't a programmer? I believe he is, you can't say otherwise just because you can't change that logic

Comment: I say if Archimedes had to deal with one person who recommended a change, he's a programmer. Whether he could make the change or not isn't imporatant (This may also be the first use of YAGNI.).

Comment: I dispute that the Antikythera mechanism was a computer, hence it's not undisputed!!  As brilliant a device as it was, it was really just a very clever clock. It's machine fabrication technology was about 500-1000 years ahead of its time, but it was in no way 'programmable'.  Clocks are not computers.

Comment: @Jim In Texas. An algorithm can be represented physically in the hardware itself. Creating and representing the algorithm in some form is programming. You can program with wooden sticks, using water flow as the "current" or equivalent of electricity. The "programming" occurs while making the machine, rather than afterwards.

Comment: @mike Hmm, that reminds me of the analog computer in Neal Stephenson's "Cryptonomicon". That was created out of pipe organ parts. What about programming genes by means of a [DNA computer](http://www.economist.com/node/21548488)?

Comment: @JimInTexas OK - edited to accept your dispute

Comment: @JimInTexas The Antikythera mechanism is generally accepted as a form of [analog computer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_computer). The fact that the programming is only done once (during construction) doesn't make it less of a computer, in that respect the mechanism is no different than Alan Turing's [Bombe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombe) or the [Atanasoff–Berry Computer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atanasoff%E2%80%93Berry_Computer).

Comment: @YannisRizos - I have actually programmed analog computers.  They are general purpose machines that can be used to solve many different problems.  The Antikythera has been pretty clearly determined to be a very fancy clock.  A clock isn't a computer, analog or digital.